# Plugin for Google App Gmail

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, enterprise

I am new to Google Apps. A small company's email is hosted in Google Mail server using Google Apps. I want to know if there is any way to write a plugin for Google App Gmail like scanning the email to mark is important or do some addition processing ?
A small tutorial to achieve the same is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Check out the answers for this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819528/gmail-plugin-api-development

Comment: @ysalmi the post you gave in reference unfortunately only contain broken links

Comment: A little bit of googling reveals this: https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample snippet that will mark all messages from a particular sender as Important.

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('from:example.com');
for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i][0].markImportant();
}
```